# Carousel Bootstrap 5.2 wrong sliding down

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I am creating a carousel.
When the images are sliding, it first appears down and then it jumps up on the correct level as shown in the image below. I tried to add height, more width or auto, do not change.

[image: wrong sliding]

I took the code on the doc of Bootstrap adding my images :

```
                  <div class="carousel-indicators">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <img src="media/paysage Ecu.webp" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="Montain">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>First slide label</h5>
                        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="media/galapagos view.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="galapagos view">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="media/forest.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="forest">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block img-fluid">
                        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                  </button>
                  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                  </button>
                </div><div id="carouselIndex" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                  <div class="carousel-indicators">
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <img src="media/paysage Ecu.webp" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="Montain">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>First slide label</h5>
                        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="media/galapagos view.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="galapagos view">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="media/forest.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="forest">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block img-fluid">
                        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                  </button>
                  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndex" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
```

CSS :

```
#carouselIndex {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 60vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `Betastrap 5.2` and I didn't see any problem. Probably, there is an interference with the **theme** of your site.
Please change the theme and check.
And use the bootstrap data below.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried and I think is work. I had an other link ref. Only one line :/

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: Yes. I changed as well the margin. It was set to 0, I put it back to auto. Everything works as it should. :)